# Combinar duas ou mais types e tuplas no Typescript

Tags: typescript, react

No trecho abaixo, tenho os seguintes `types`:

```js
// eg.:
type ButtonTypeModifiers = 'is-primary' | 'is-secondary'
type ButtonMarginModifiers = 'has-margin' | 'has-no-margin' | 'has-no-margin-mobile'
type ButtonSizeModifiers = 'is-mall' | 'is-large' | 'is-large-mobile' | 'is-extra-large-mobile'

type ButtonProps = {
  id: string
  // ---> a linha abaixo é onde está o meu desafio <---
  modifiers: [ButtonTypeModifiers, ButtonMarginModifiers, ButtonSizeModifiers]
}
```

Com o código acima, eu consegui o seguinte:

```js
<Button id="test" modifiers={['is-primary', 'has-margin', 'is-large']}
```

Mas, eu preciso de algo como:

```js
<Button id="test" modifiers={['has-margin', 'is-primary', 'has-no-margin-mobile', 'is-large', 'is-extra-large-mobile']} />
```

Preciso combinar várias `types` em `tuples` dentro de um `array`.
A *tupla* ocupa uma posição do `array` e me obriga a preencher com uma opção e segura essa posição, porem, em um `array` preciso usar vários do valores dos meus `types`.

Em resumo, dentro de um todas os valores que estão nos meus types `Button...Modifiers` são elegíveis para usar como valor na propriedade que eu preciso *tipar*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quiser criar um tipo para um *array* combinando os tipos que você já tem, pode fazer assim:

```
type Modifiers = Array<ButtonTypeModifiers | ButtonMarginModifiers | ButtonSizeModifiers>;
```

Ou, com a sintaxe alternativa:

```
type Modifiers = (ButtonTypeModifiers | ButtonMarginModifiers | ButtonSizeModifiers)[];
```

Desse modo, `Modifiers` vai aceitar um *array* com elementos de qualquer um dos tipos formados pela [união](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

Saiba mais sobre *arrays* [nesta documentação](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array).